# Properly formatted PHP function call failing

Tags: php

I dread having to ask questions when I know the answer is going to be something very dumb, but here goes! I have 3 pages that I'm using. My edit_financials.php page is where I'm having the error. This page calls my config.php file, which intializes some site-wide stuff and instantiates the util.php page as util.

Other function calls to the same util.php work just fine, but for some reason, this one is causing everything to fail.

I've isolated it to this one line:

```
$profileInfo = $util->getProfile();
```

Which calls the following function:

```
public function getProfile(){

$user = $this->getLoggedInUser();

$result = $this->DBQuery("SELECT firstname, middleinit, lastname, addr1, addr2, city, state, zip, email FROM user WHERE userId=$user");

if(!$result){
    return false;

} else {

    return $result;
}

return false;

}
```

The block of code on edit_financials.php is:

```
$profileInfo = $util->getProfile();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($profileInfo)){

        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $mi = $row['middleinit'];
        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $address1 = $row['addr1'];
        $address2 =$row['addr2'];
        $city =$row['city'];
        $state = $row['state'];
        $zip = $row['zip'];

}
```

As you can see, I'm tryign to pass the result set back to edit_financials.php and then loop through it to get the values for my variables. I'm not even sure if I can do this, or maybe I should do the loop in util and pass back an array with all the values?

I know the error has to be here somewhere, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Update: 
I'm working on adding asserts (Learning something new today) in the meantime I added a couple more echos to see if it's even entering the function and it appears that it is not...

Added to edit_financials:

```
echo " About to call that pesky getProfile() function.... ";    

$profileInfo = $util->getProfile(); 

echo " We're back to edit_financials now... ";
```

Added to util:
    public function getProfile(){

```
echo " Function is running.... ";

// and I commented everything else out

}
```

And my output is:

"About to call that pesky getProfile() function...."

And that's it. So it's not even entering the function, which is why I can't get a vardump.

Comment: Are you sure `getLoggedInUser();` returns the user correctly?

Comment: @Fabio Good question, I am sure. I validated that in my test it replies with "50" as it should, I even confirmed the mySQL query runs fine with that 50 added in place of the variable.

Comment: `var_dump($profileInfo)`

Comment: Below the statement `$result = $this->DBQuery("...`, type `var_dump($result);`. What do you see as the output of var_dump?

Comment: So, `$util` is not an object? Have you enabled all warnings and errors? Checked the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Add assert "everywhere" to track it down. Good habit, anyway. Do you get an error message? If not, then you might want to get into more defensive programming.

Since `getProfile` can return false, it is not correct to use the result from that function without checking for false. Also, don't use `!$result`, but `$result === null` or similar.

For easier unit testing, `getProfile()` should be `getProfile($userId)`.

As mentioned in the comments, `getLoggedInUser()` should be `getLoggedInUserID()`.

Also, use prepared statements, always.

Enable all errors and warnings.

Comment: This should really be a comment

Comment: @Fabio The question should more be in the head of the OP. He should have narrowed down on the problem. That would have either provided an obvious solution or at least a workaround to some third party software bug or quirky behaviour. 
I find this to be a good answer.

Comment: I am narrowing it down, and clearly I need additional help. This was a helpful comment, not a helpful answer.

Comment: @Fabio Yeah, it was, but I kept expanding it, so.